# how to update code that was deployed on host server with DockerFile?

Tags: deployment, dockerfile

i have a fullstack app i deployed:

MySQL DB - was deployed on AWS RDS,

Backend, spring boot was deployed on render,

Frontend, react also deployed on render.

When i looked for tutorial how to deployed my spring boot backend, all of them did it by adding DockerFile

so i did that too.

now the fullstack app is deployed and working good. but when i try to change something in my spring boot backend from Github, changes not showing even after manually deployed last commit in render. after i did some reading i understand it was cause i deployed it with dockerfile and I cant just do changes in the code in GitHub like i normally do.. that DockerFile build an image that keep the application isolated.

from what i read about Dockers i need to add a file "docker-compose.yml" to let me do change in the code base more easly.. but i dont know what to write in this file to allow me do that. also i am not sure if what i have in my DockerFile is enough.

here is my DockerFile:

```
FROM eclipse-temurin:11-jdk-alpine
VOLUME /tmp
COPY target/*.jar app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.jar"]
EXPOSE 8080
```

here is my Backend Files(if needed):

[Backend application Files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H4Riq.png)

when i googled for answer.. i got many example how to update code on application run with docker..

i think my situation is different cause i cant get access to the container that was created in build time from the DockerFile.

sorry in advance if i write some wrong facts.. i am not very familiar with docker technology.

Thank you all very much